# My application shows blank space under keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

My application shows blank space under keyboard.
When I click on edittext box, it shows soft keyboard (system default) but displays some blank space under keyboard.

My screen is 5.5" and model number is Asus Zenfone with Android 6.0.1

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity.LoginActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

My Layout.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/llParent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/capacities_list_actionbar_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CapacitiesCollapsedAppBar"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/capacities_list_expandedtitle_margin_bottom"
                app:scrimAnimationDuration="70"
                app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CapacitiesExpandedAppBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:title="Login">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/capacities_list_subtitle_text_size"
                        android:lines="2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/capacities_list_subtitle_bottom_margin"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/capacities_list_subtitle_left_margin"
                        android:text="@string/login_to_the_capacity_owner_s_app"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white_light"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/capacities_list_subtitle_left_margin" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblSignup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_signup_button_margin"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_signup_button_margin"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/sign_up"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/login_login_button_text_size" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="7dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/style_header_shadow"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/login_linearlayout_padding">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_space_margin">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/email"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    app:font_style="BOLD"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/txtLoginEmail"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:hint="e.g. johdoe@xyz.com"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_dul"
                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_edittext_text_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>


                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imgLoginRightSign"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/login_right_sign_image_width"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/login_right_sign_image_hight"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/login_right_sign_image_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_right_sign_image_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_right_sign_image_top_margin"
                                android:background="@drawable/right_sign_green_icon"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/viewEmailLine"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:background="#909090"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblEmailErrorMessage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@color/line_error_color"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:text=""/>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_space_margin">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="@string/password"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    app:font_style="BOLD"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_3sdp"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/txtLoginPassword"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:hint="e.g.***********"
                                    android:background="#fff"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_black"
                                    android:textColorHint="@color/color_dul"
                                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                                    android:maxLength="12"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/login_edittext_text_size" />
                            </LinearLayout>

                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                            <ImageView
                                android:visibility="gone"
                                android:id="@+id/imgLoginEyeIcon"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/signup_eye_image_width"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/signup_eye_image_hight"
                                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/signup_eye_image_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/signup_eye_image_right_margin"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/signup_eye_image_top_margin"
                                android:background="@drawable/eye_visible" />

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/viewPasswordLine"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="2dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:background="#909090"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lblPasswdErrorMessage"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/line_error_color"
                            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                            android:paddingStart="5dp" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/login_space_margin"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:padding="@dimen/login_next_button_padding"
                            android:text="@string/login"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/login_next_button_text_size" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lblForgotPassword"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
                        android:textColor="@color/color_dark_blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/login_forgot_password_button_text_size" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have attached screenshot with keyboard issue. [image]

Comment: Strange. Are you sure that this is system keypad or any 3rd party application?

Comment: I m sure, this is system keyboard. i m not using any third party keyboard app.

Comment: I have the same problem. It appeared from nowhere. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you used *NestedScrollView* That doesn't match the full height with behavior `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` that behavior make the bottom layout joined with the bottom of `AppBarLayout`.

**Note:** You need to use *NestedScrollView* if you have content to scroll in.

Otherwise: The keyboard should be at bottom, so this issue maybe in your device only.